# Jest: Mock one function in a class

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm very new to node and javascript, and trying to write a unittet with `jest` where I need to only mock 1 function of a class (and object).

Here's a template I'm using:

```
// myModule.js
class MyModule {
    constructor() {
      console.log("hello");
    }
    getCases(){
        return 2;
    }
    getOtherCases(){
        return 3;
    }
}
module.exports = MyModule;
```

and the test:

```
// myModule.test.js
jest.unmock('./myModule.js');
const myModule = require('./myModule.js');
myModule.getCases = jest.fn();

describe('Test mock function', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        myModule.getCases.mockImplementation(() => 32);
        mod = new myModule();
    });

    it('should pass', () => {
        console.log(mod.getCases());
        console.log(myModule.getCases());
    });
  });
```

The problem over here is `mod.getCases()` does not mock the function (`myModule.getCases()` does)

```
console.log myModule.test.js:12
2


console.log myModule.test.js:13
32
```

Is there a specific way I need to create the object so it would mock the function?

Comment: Try `myModule.prototype.getCases` in place of `myModule.getCases`. If this is the solution I will explain in an answer.

Comment: yep that works! it'd be great if you provide the answer as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must replace all `MyModule.getCases` with `MyModule.prototype.getCases`.

This is because the `class` syntax is just [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). Without this you would instead have (and indeed we used to do this).

```
function MyModule () {
    console.log('hello')
}

MyModule.prototype.getCases = function () {
    return 2;
};

MyModule.prototype.getOtherCases = function () {
    return 3;
};

module.exports = MyModule;
```

This is completely equivalent to your code and if you copied and pasted it you would see it worked in the same way.

As all objects created with `new` inherit the `prototype`, the above syntax is just a very manual way of creating shared functions for instances of objects. Prototypal inheritance can be quite confusing at first, and it took me a while to get it too, but you can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMfcsYzj-9M) is quite good also.

When you were performing `myModule.getCases` in your tests were not actually modifying the prototype property which your instance (created with `new`) would inherit.

Now seeing that `getCases` inside your `class` syntax and `getCases` on the prototype are the same thing, hopefully you can see why the replacement solves your problem.

If I haven't explained anything very clearly or you want me to clarify anything feel free to ask.